# How to assign numeric labels to the columns of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2

I have a matrix similar to the following in a file.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8   9   10  11 12
4 5 5 6 7 8 9 10  11  12  13 3
```

(This data is just for presentation. My actual data is pretty big to include here.)
I want to plot a heat map of it using ggplot2. Here is the code I use:

```
T=read.table("file")
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

Y=melt(as.matrix(T))

ggplot(Y)+
  geom_tile(aes(x=Var2, y=Var1,fill = value))
```

The problem is that Var2 has alpha-numeric values and so `ggplo2` orders it in lexicographic way.
How can I tell R to give numerical labels to columns like it does to rows? (Or there may be a better solution?)

[image]

Comment: You should really avoid to use `T` as a variable name, since it also stands for `TRUE` in R

Comment: I cannot reproduce. When I run your example, `Y$Var2` is `Factor`, not `character`, and its `levels(Y$Var2)` are rightly ordered as `[1] "V1"  "V2"  "V3"` rather than `[1] "V1"  "V10"  "V11"`

Comment: Save var2 as a factor and order its levels as desired.

Comment: @raistlin Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most beautiful way to do it but :

Recovering number of var by doing :

```
Y$number<-substr(Y$X2,2,length(Y$X2))
```

then following code (`limits` forces the order of X, `labels` pastes anything you want) :

```
ggplot(Y)+
geom_tile(aes(x=X2, y=X1,fill = value))+
scale_x_discrete(limits=c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5","V6","V7","V8","V9","V10","V11","V12"),labels=Y$number)
```

gives
[image]

or as you suggested :

```
ggplot(Y)+
geom_tile(aes(x=X2, y=X1,fill = value))+
scale_x_discrete(limits=c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5","V6","V7","V8","V9","V10","V11","V12"),labels=1:12)
```

gives [image]